# Who is credited with the discovery of rolling friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, history

Which physicians discovered and/or contributed at large to what we know of rolling friction today, and what exactly did they contribute?

Comment: Would this be better on history of science SE? https://hsm.stackexchange.com/